# get nth text variable within a specific class/id in html using cypress

Tags: html, jquery, cypress

I'm new to cypress and lately I have to extract text variables within websites using cypress. Now, I've finally figured out how to extract text variables of a specific class/id in html. However, I cannot find the right way to extract **the exact nth element within the class/id**.

For example, here is my html:

```
             <div class ="main-menu-wrapper align-self-stretch align-items-stretch" id="navbarCollaspse">
                <ul region="header" class="clearfix nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-center mx-auto">
                  
                    <li class="nav-item menu-item--expanded dropdown">
                     <a href="https://example/subwebsite/aaaaa" 
                      class="nav-link dropdown-toggle main-menu-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"> 
                       TEXTAAAAA </a>
            
                    <li class="nav-item menu-item--expanded dropdown">
                     <a href="https://example/subwebsite/bbbbb" 
                      class="nav-link dropdown-toggle main-menu-2" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                      aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"> 
                      TEXTBBBBBB </a>
        
                     <li class="nav-item menu-item--expanded dropdown">
                     <a href="https://example/subwebsite/ccccc" 
                      class="nav-link dropdown-toggle main-menu-3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
 expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"> 
                TEXTCCCCCC </a>
     </div>
```

Here is my cypress javascript code:

```
cy.visit('https://example/website')
    cy.get([class="clearfix nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-center mx-auto"]).each(($el) => {
      cy.wrap($el).invoke('text')
        .then(text => {
     //do something with the text
    //Here, I could get TEXTAAAAA TEXTBBBBBB TEXTCCCCCC orderly, however, i want to extract only TEXTBBBBBB
        })
    })
```

Now, when I `cy.get([class="clearfix nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-center mx-auto"]).each($el)` I could get  `TEXTAAAAA TEXTBBBBBB TEXTCCCCCC`. However, now, I only want to get the second element within the class , in this case, `TEXTBBBBBB`. I tried to reference the way [from here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) but cypress couldn't found the path.
Any ideas on how to get specific element within a class using cypress is a great help! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the text for a particular element, you can do it by using the index value, it should look something like this. Here we ae extracting the second element.

```
cy.get('locator').each(($el, index) => {
   if (index == 1) {
      cy.wrap($el).invoke('text').then((text) => {
         //do something with the text
      })
   }
})
```

Comment: thank you for your advice, but actually I need to extract many websites all at once (their structure are the same, but contents are different), so I cannot hard code my text content to extract the element. Is there any other possible way to reach that element?

Comment: So for every website you need to only extract the text for second element and the text can be anything ?

Comment: @AlapanDas why not use `.eq(2)` instead of this usage of `each`?